# Images displayed twice as image is uploaded as featured image in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image-scaling

[Images displayed twice as image is uploaded as featured image in WordPress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlvo7.jpg) am displaying as boxed style but another thumbnails is displayed under boxed style.

Comment: You can remove that second image from code.

Answer (score 0):

Without the link to the page, I will not be able to give you the exact CSS code, but in child theme or if your theme has a section to input custom CSS, you can hide the extra image by using `display:none;`

In Chrome, right click on the extra image and select 'Inspect'. See the CSS class of the image you want to hide.

Add your CSS class like so:

```
.extraimagecssclass { display: none; }
```

You might have to use `!important` to override the CSS from the main theme.

Comment: I added the code , but yesterday only i published this article and showing same issue  https://www.freearticlessource.com/real-estate-virtual-assistant.html

Comment: @stackovergk The image you want to remove has CSS defined within the page code and has no unique class. Hence, you will have to remove it from the code in order to get rid of that thumbnail

Comment: @stackovergk A plugin or theme is adding this bit of code to your page `img src="imagesource" width="150" height="86" style="display:inline-block"` You need to find where it is getting added from and then delete it